# Adding datepicker date with integer

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have my code where I have three fields,

1. datepicker
2. an input field for integer value
3. an input box for showing resulting date.

I select the datepicker date and it reads in `dd/mm/yyyy` format, say `06/02/2018`. Now I enter an integer value in next input box and click a button to show resulting date after adding integer to the date selected. On result my date shows in `mm-dd-yyyy` format with that integer added to the month part of the selected date i.e. if I add 3 days to my selected date `06/02/2018` it should show `09/02/2018` but instead it displays the resulting date as `06/05/2018`.

How can this resolve? Any insight and input are welcome.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<div class="panel panel-primary">
  <div class="panel-heading">Registration Parameters</div>
  <br><br>
  <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="" >
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <label for="username" class="control-label"><b>Date from:</b></label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8 input-group date" >
          <input id="txtDate"  name="title"  class="form-control" placeholder="Start Date" value="" >
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <label for="username" class="control-label"><b>New Date formed:</b></label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <div class="input-group date">
            <input id="follow_Date"  name="days_for_start" disabled class="form-control"  value="" >
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <br><br><br><br>
      <input type="button" id="btn"  value="Check New Date" />
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <label for="username" class="control-label"><b>Extension days:</b></label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <input id="extdays" type="text" name="days_for_end"  class="form-control"  required="" value="" >
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
      
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#txtDate').datepicker({
      dateFormat:'mm/dd/yy',
    });
  });

  function getdate() {
    var tt = document.getElementById('txtDate').value;
    var input = document.getElementById('extdays').value;
    if (input == "" || input==null){
      input =0
    }
    if(tt != ''){
      var date = new Date(tt);
      var newdate = new Date(tt);
      newdate.setDate(newdate.getDate() + parseInt(input));

      var dd = newdate.getDate();
      var mm = newdate.getMonth() + 1;
      var y = newdate.getFullYear();

      var someFormattedDate = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + y;
    
      document.getElementById('follow_Date').value = someFormattedDate;
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got the result. Had to parse the input date and convert,

```
    <script>  

    $(document).ready(function () {

       $( "#txtDate" ).datepicker({
            //dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"
            dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"
        });
      });
    function getdate() {
        var tt = document.getElementById('txtDate').value;
        var input = document.getElementById('extdays').value;
        if (input == "" || input==null)
        {
          input =0
        }


    var initial = tt.split(/\//).reverse().join('/'); // to change the format

        var date = new Date(initial);
        var newdate = new Date(date);


       newdate.setDate(newdate.getDate() + parseInt(input));

        var dd = newdate.getDate();
        var mm = newdate.getMonth() + 1;
        var y = newdate.getFullYear();

        var someFormattedDate = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + y;
        document.getElementById('follow_Date').value = someFormattedDate;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

**I did some changes and it's working now check this answer**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <label for="username" class="control-label"><b>Date from:</b></label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8 input-group date" >
                <input id="txtDate"  name="title" maxlength="150" class="form-control" placeholder="Start Date" value="" >

                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <label for="username" class="control-label"><b>New Date formed:</b></label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                  <div class="input-group date">
               <input id="follow_Date" type="text" name="days_for_start" disabled class="form-control"  value="" >
                </div>
                </div>
                </div><br><br> <br><br>
                 <input type="button" onclick="getdate()" value="Check New Date" />
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <label for="username" class="control-label"><b>Extension days:</b></label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
               <input id="extdays" type="text" name="days_for_end"  class="form-control"  required="" value="" >
                </div>
              </div>
              </div>
              <script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#txtDate').datepicker({
   
    dateFormat:'mm/dd/yy',
   
});
    });


  function getdate() {
  var tt = document.getElementById('txtDate').value;
  var input = document.getElementById('extdays').value;
  if (input == "" || input==null){
    input =0
  }
  if(tt != ''){
    var date = new Date(tt);
    var newdate = new Date(tt);


    newdate.setDate(newdate.getDate() + parseInt(input));

    var dd = newdate.getDate();
    var mm = newdate.getMonth() + 1;
    var y = newdate.getFullYear();

    var someFormattedDate = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + y;
    
    document.getElementById('follow_Date').value = someFormattedDate;
  }
  }

  </script>
```

Comment: I have tried this also. And the snippet you posted does the same as my script does.

Comment: Yes i did  some changes.
one is removed jquery.min.js from your code

Comment: Yes I saw. But still friend. Its doing the same

Comment: it's because of  date format, check with mm/dd/yy format it's working properly.
i am checking for the dd/mm/yy format

Comment: I have applied both the formats but the results stays exactly the same.

Comment: Is it okay if i will use mm/dd/yyyy format in your case ?

Comment: check the answer now with mm/dd/yy format it's working

Comment: Actually in all the cases its adding the integer to month only but not date

Comment: Changing the format won't help for me. I need both fields to show data in d/m/y

Comment: check the snippet it's addded date not month.

Comment: Changing the format won't help for me. I need both fields to show data in d/m/y  - For this i m working on it will update you asap

Comment: Even on changing its taking the selected date in `dd/mm/yyyy` format

Comment: I have again edited my code. Please take a look. @Priyank

Comment: @Ansh do not mix jquery and bootstrap remove jquery-2.1.3.min.js and bootstrap css from your form.

Comment: Please take a look. Changed . @Priyank

Answer (score 1):

hope this will help

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <label for="username" class="control-label"><b>Date from:</b></label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8 input-group date" >
                <input id="txtDate"  name="title" maxlength="150" class="form-control" placeholder="Start Date" value="" >

                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <label for="username" class="control-label"><b>New Date formed:</b></label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                  <div class="input-group date">
               <input id="follow_Date" type="text" name="days_for_start" disabled class="form-control"  value="" >
                </div>
                </div>
                </div><br><br> <br><br>
                 <input type="button" onclick="getdate()" value="Check New Date" />
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <label for="username" class="control-label"><b>Extension days:</b></label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
               <input id="extdays" type="text" name="days_for_end"  class="form-control"  required="" value="" >
                </div>
              </div>
              </div>
              <script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#txtDate').datepicker({
   
    dateFormat:'mm/dd/yy',
   
});
    });


  function getdate() {
  var tt = document.getElementById('txtDate').value;
  var input = document.getElementById('extdays').value;
  if (input == "" || input==null){
    input =0
  }
  if(tt != ''){
    var date = new Date(tt);
    var newdate = new Date(tt);


    newdate.setDate(newdate.getDate() + parseInt(input));

    var dd = newdate.getDate();
    var mm = newdate.getMonth() + 1;
    var y = newdate.getFullYear();

    var someFormattedDate = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + y;
    
    document.getElementById('follow_Date').value = someFormattedDate;
  }
  }

  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you need to parse your DateString into Date -

```
tt = $.datepicker.parseDate("dd/mm/yy",tt);
```

Your updated script is-

```
 function getdate() {  
  var tt = document.getElementById('txtDate').value;
  var input = document.getElementById('extdays').value;
  if (input == "" || input==null){
    input =0
  }
  if(tt != ''){
   tt = $.datepicker.parseDate("dd/mm/yy",tt);
    var date = new Date(tt);
    var newdate = new Date(tt);


    newdate.setDate(newdate.getDate() + parseInt(input));

    var dd = newdate.getDate();
    var mm = newdate.getMonth() + 1;
    var y = newdate.getFullYear();

    var someFormattedDate = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + y;

    document.getElementById('follow_Date').value = someFormattedDate;
  }
  }
```

Comment: You need to add  tt = $.datepicker.parseDate("dd/mm/yy",tt); in your script code.

Comment: `console.log(someFormattedDate)` says $.datepicker is undefined.

Comment: Yes your fiddle is working right. For me as i said earlier `console.log(someFormattedDate) says $.datepicker is undefined.`